# How to select the second row in SQL injection?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I was practicing SQL injection on a private books library website search bar and the search bar has only one input field.

And as expected

```
' OR '1'='1' --
' OR 1=1 --
```

both return the first row in the database but I was trying to get the second and third row, too and tried this to get the second row.

```
' OR '1'='1' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1 --
```

but it's replying no books exist so why isn't this working and what is the correct format for this to work.

I have full permission from the site owner and this is purely only for studying purposes.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: This will depend entirely on how the app is written, as to whether it ends up being valid sql. If you have access to the sql profiler to see exactly the sql being run, then you should be able to construct your injection code correctly.

Comment: but this should have worked ryt?

Comment: You dont know how else the query is constructed. If the last part of the query was the where clause, then it might. If there was something after the where clauses then it might not. `where name='tom' or 1=1` would probably always work. `where name='tom' or 1=1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1 group by...` for example would not.